# Can I have both 'Organization' as well as 'LocalBusiness' schema on the homepage?

Tags: schema.org, homepage

Can I have both `Organization` schema as well as `LocalBusiness` schema on the homepage?

In the `Organization` schema, I haven't put much information, but in the `LocalBusiness` I have put all the information including the address etc.

Comment: Why do you want to have both?

Answer (score 0):

LocalBusiness is a more specific type derived from Organization. You can move all your properties that you added in Organization into your LocalBusiness markup, and remove the need of the Organization. The schema documentation gives some clues:

https://schema.org/LocalBusiness

The breadcrumb indicates what type LocalBusiness derives from.

The properties list show which properties are added by LocalBusiness as well as the properties it inherits from Organization.